# Python PySimpleGUI abrindo a tela errada

Tags: python

Tenho um crawler utilizando PySimpleGUI para definir os dados a serem coletados e Selenium para a coleta de dados. Após a definição dos dados através de uma window criada pelo sg.Window(), eu crio uma sg.PopupAnimated indicando o status do Crawler, porém ao executar na IDE PyCharm funciona corretamente, após gerar o EXE através do PyInstaller, Auto-py-to-exe ou CX_Freeze no lugar de gerar o Popup ele exibe novamente a tela, segue o código abaixo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys
import re
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

def getDados():
    global nome
    global email
    global user

    sg.SetOptions(text_justification='right')
    layout =[[sg.Text('Nome',size=(23,1)), sg.Input()],
            [sg.Text('E-mail',size=(23,1)), sg.Input()],
            [sg.Text('Nome e Sobrenome',size=(23,1)), sg.Input()],
            [sg.Submit('OK', pad=((420, 5), 5)), sg.Exit('Cancelar', pad=((5, 0), 5))]]
    window = sg.Window('Gera', layout, finalize=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit' or event == 'Cancelar':
            sys.exit(0)
        elif event == 'OK':
            #Valida se todos estão preenchidos
            if(values[0] =='' or values[1] =='' or values[2] ==''):
                sg.popup('Preencha todos os campos')
                continue
            # Valida formato do email
            elif (re.search("[a-z0-9.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]", values[1]) == None or ' 'in values[1]):
                sg.popup('É Necessário Informar um e-mail Válido')
                continue
            # Valida se existe nome e sobrenome
            elif(re.search(". .", values[2]) == None):
                sg.popup('É Necessário Informar Nome e Sobrenome')
                continue
             else:
                 nome = values[0].upper()
                 email = values[1]
                 user = values[2]
                 window.close()
                 del window
                 return

def alerta(msg):
    while(True):
        sg.PopupAnimated('loading.gif', time_between_frames=100, message = msg, font ='Courier 12', keep_on_top=True)

def thread(desc,pare):
    if(pare == None and desc == None):
        pare.terminate()
        return
    if(pare!= None):
        pare.terminate()
    if(desc == None):
        pare.terminate()
        return
    th = multiprocessing.Process(target=alerta,args=(desc,))
    th.start()
    return th

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sg.SetGlobalIcon('logo.ico')
    getDados()
    th = thread('Aguarde', None)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=resource_path('chromedriver.exe'))
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

    try:
        try:
            th = thread('Logando', th)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            th = thread(None, th)
            sg.popup_error('Erro ao Efetuar o Login')

        time.sleep(60)
        try:
            th = thread('Acesando Perfil', th)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            th = thread(None, th)
            sg.popup_error('Erro ao Acesar Perfil')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file('erro.png')
```

Sempre que executado o comando `sg.PopupAnimated()` o software abre a tela da função `getDados()`. Porém isso somente ocorre após a geração do EXE, enquanto eu rodo o código .py pela IDE ele funcionar normal, exibindo o PopUp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, descobri a solução do problema, ele estava exibindo a mesma janela pois eu estava utilizando o multiprocessing.Process(), devido ele criar uma nova instância para execução, ele acabava executando novamente a função getDados(). Para corrigir o problema precisei efetuar algumas alterações, uma delas foi alterar multiprocessing por Thread(), que corrigiu o problema da abertura das janelas. Porém como eu não conseguia finalizar a Thread, eu utilizei apenas uma Thread para executar o Crawler, e no **main** mantive a janela onde era exibido os status. Desta forma criei uma variável para indicar o status e apenas verificava ela em um While dentro do Main.